# How can I get visitor ID from Piwik via JavaScript?

Tags: api, cookies, browser-cache, matomo

I tried this:

```
var visitor_id;    
    _paq.push([ function () { visitor_id = this.getVisitorId(); }]);
```

This are working perfect until I clear the browser cookies, once I clear the browser cookies, Piwik getVisitorId() isn't bringing the old visitor ID. Piwik is still tracking under the old visitor ID itself, I just want to retrieve it.

You can see the error on one of the client sites here: https://www.artsocket.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var visitor_id;
_paq.push([ function() { visitor_id = this.getVisitorId(); }]);
```

This one works for sure if cookies are enabled in the browser. It takes the visitor ID from Piwik's _pk_id cookie. It's also the recommended version to get the cookie because in this case you are not creating a new tracker object.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, will test this and reply quick

Comment: I have updated my question with more specific details and code. Above code is not bringing correct visitor id. Am I suppose to enable something in piwik or any where else? Thank you very much for helping out.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, your answer did work!! Cheers :)